# Calling a PHP returning a JSON returns an error though I can see the response

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

This is the javascript I'm using to make an AJAX call to a PHP:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                country: "uk"
            },
            url: 'http://api.mysite.uk/advertorial/index.php',
            success: function (response){
                var result = $.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error : function () {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

which returns a JSON structured like this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"test","country":"uk","header":"Header","pre_cta_text":"Pre CTA","cta_text":"CTA text","cta":"CTA","img":null,"active":"1"}
```

Even if the call gives an error, I can see that it's returning the JSON above. I particular the error I get in browser console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>   index.php?callback=jQuery32103297264247416809_1516181997373&country=uk&_=1516181997374:1

Comment: The posted JSON is valid. Are there any invisible charachters in front of your first opening bracket?

Comment: add console.log(response) (or check network log of developer tools) to see what you have got from the server.

Comment: Errrm, if you are parsing json why `dataType` is `jsonp`?

Answer (score 1):

You instruct jQuery to ask for JSONP and decode it automatically:

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Then you take jQuery's decoded data and handle it as JSON, which is not and has never been:

```
success: function (response){
    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(result);
}
```